# Swing event not fired by a user

Tags: java, events

Which are other events than timer not fired by user interaction but
automatically by the system?

Answer (score 0):

I will say that none or better all.

Thats depend of that what are you doing in the system. You can fire all type of events in your application. It can be sad that some of them are fired by user interaction, bu it is up to You to decide that what the interaction.

Answer (score 0):

A reasonable distinction is between events entering the AWT `EventQueue` through "the system" and those explicitly queued (possibly through AWT libraries). Without *any* permissions these will come through `EventQueue.invokeLater` and `EventQueue.invokeAndWait`, causing an `InvocationEvent`. `javax.swing.Timer` and `revalidate` are typically implemented with `invokeLater`. It is also possible to get the current `EventQueue` instance a post any event you want.

It is also possible to go through "the system" to cause events, such as `repaint` and `java.awt.Robot`.